# Xbee pro series 2b und TGS 2602 -receiving value are wrong and doesn´t change

Tags: arduino, xbee

i have a arduino uno, xbee pro series 2 b and a voc-sensor: tgs 2602.
i want to send the resistance´s value of the sensor through xbee to the serial monitor from arduino.
tgs2602--> xbee    -    xbee-->xbee shield-->arduino uno

i configure my first xbee as a router in AT Modus with sample rate 1000ms and my coordinator in API.
the sketch i used look like this:

```
//Remote XBee:AT, Base XBee:API
float voc;
void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
};

void loop(){

if(Serial.available() >=21){ //Makesure the frame is all there
if (Serial.read()== 0x7E){ //7E is the start byte
for (int i = 1; i<18; i++) { //Skip ahead to the analog data
 byte discardByte = Serial.read();

}
int analogMSB = Serial.read(); // Read the first analog byte data
int analogLSB = Serial.read(); //Read the second byte
int analogReading = analogLSB + (analogMSB * 256);

float volt = analogReading/1023.0 * 5 ;    // Rechne die von ADC ausgegebenen Werten in Volt um
float Rs1 = 10*(5-volt)/volt;        //Rechne den Widerstandswert


Serial.println(Rs1);
}
}
}
```

i took this code in an example in youtube.

The data i received in the serial monitor is 5105. This value doesn´t change even when i touch the sensor.

Why?
Am i doing something wrong.

I need your help.

Thanks

Comment: You might want to look a the frame type and make sure it's correct.  The XBee will send you status frames in addition to your analog readings.  Perhaps dump the entire frame to make sure it's correct and you're parsing it correctly, and/or dump the LSB and MSB values read.

Comment: Hi tomlogic, i´ve done that!! The "discardByte = 0
18
146
0
125
51
162
0
64
173
23
24
85
236
1
1
0".

Comment: 146 = 0x92, so this is a data sample.  What are `analogMSB` and `analogLSB`?  Do they vary?  Is the sensor connected to the first analog input (A0)?

Comment: Hi tomlogic, analogMSB = 2, analogLSB=0, they don´t vary.the sensor is connected to the 2nd analog input.  (sorry for the late answers)

Comment: HI,i´m using a xbee regulated breakout board and i want to know if the problem can be the voltage.

Comment: You may need to configure `ATD1` as an analog input (set it to 2), and `ATD0` as disabled, if you're using the 2nd analog input.  Or move your sensor to the first analog input.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're configuring everything up correctly for the analog input.  Digi has a good tutorial on [configuring an analog input with a potentiometer](http://examples.digi.com/sensors/802-15-4-analog-input-with-a-potentiometer/3/).  Follow those steps and get something that works, and then gradually make changes until you're reading your sensor on the Arduino.

For example, once you have the potentiometer working on the XBee and a PC, connect it to the Arduino and make sure the readings are correct.  Then replace the potentiometer with your sensor, and see if the readings are still correct.

Comment: I used the sensor without xbee and its works very well. But with xbee i get this wrong values. Maybe it´s the voltage, i will try to use some more resistor and divide the voltage. the tutorial i followed is in youtube from tunnelsup (reading analo data from remote xbee)